# Can you trigger Quicksilver with Shift-Space?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, quicksilver

I was using launchy on Windows, and I'm finally using its original OS X counter-part Quicksilver.

I've grown accustomed to pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for triggering it, yet I don't seem to get it to work. Is there any "registry" setting I can tweak to force it to take <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as trigger?

Comment: The other question should be a separate one! Regarding the keyboard shortcut: As far as I'm concerned, there's no way you can make a keyboard shortcut anywhere in OS X that takes `Shift` plus any other key (even if it's `Space`).

Comment: @slhck Many shortcut recorders allow using just shift as a modifier key. (Even when they don't, you can sometimes modify the shortcut from a plist.) I didn't find anything in `com.blacktree.QuickSilver.plist` though.

Comment: Nik, don't delete it. Who knows, maybe some day?

Comment: @slhck okay, I won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps are tested & working in QS ß65(3920):

- Assign some other key first
- Quit Quicksilver
- Open ~/Library/Preferences/com.blacktree.Quicksilver.plist
- Under QSActivationHotKey, Change keyCode to 49, modifiers to 8519938
- Launch Quicksilver